# Page loading time

Tags: angular, typescript, user-interface

How to get pageLoad time programatically in angular.

Scenario:
I have a dashboard page, where multiple calls being made by different components.
I need to get the total time taken to load all widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to implement an intercepter(the gateway for all http calls)  https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

start recording time when the first call occurs till all the http calls are resolved

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am bit new to this concept. Can you help me how can I track these first call and last call.

Comment: check the implementation of an intercepter, every api call goes through an intercepter, so you can start the timer once you encounter the first call and then keep a counter and increment it for every call, also you can detect when an http call returns in intercepter, decrement the counter and stop the timer once all the calls are resolved i.e. the value of counter is 0

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if you want to analyze the complete page performance, you can do that in chrome

Open developer tools --> Performance -> Start Loading your page click on record button and stop it once the page loads. You can analyze how each function in your is performing.

More on this [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance)